# Calendar alert notifications block app until dismissed

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I just launched an alarm clock app and am getting reports that, if the user leaves the screen on overnight (i.e. to use it as a nightstand clock) and they receive a calendar notification (or any other notification that uses the "alert" instead of the "banner" style of notification), then the app gets blocked until the user dismisses the popup.

So, in other words, the iOS "alert" notifications are preventing the alarm clock from going off in the morning. Once the popup is dismissed, then the AVAudioPlayer starts up and the alarm goes off.

Does anyone know of a way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than instructing the user to disable these modal alerts (using the banner style alert would suffice), I don't think there's a way around it. You can't block or interrupt system alerts, which these are.